# How to add else block in Inline If with Logical && Operator in react?

Tags: reactjs, operators

I have a react code as shown below which uses inline if with logic && operator in react:

```
{ schedules && <ListItem items={schedules}/> } // Line A

{ schedules==null && <h2>Hello World</h2>} // Line B
```

Line A prints list of schedules and Line B prints `Hello World` on the webpage if there are no schedules.

I am wondering how I can merge Line A and Line B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional operator would work:

```
{ schedules ? <ListItem items={schedules}/> : <h2>Hello World</h2> }
```